# ggplot ignores color assigned

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a line graph showing the average sales of 3 neighbourhoods. Unfortunately, ggplot is ignoring the colours I have assigned to neighbourhood 1 and 3. Why is this happening and what should I do to solve the problem? Thank you.

```
ggplot(data=neighbourhood1,size=1,aes(x=sale_year, 
                                    y=price, 
                                    group=1,color="blue"))+geom_line()+
geom_line(data=neighbourhood2, size=1,aes(x=sale_year, 
                               y=price, 
                               group=1,color="green"))+
geom_line(data=neighbourhood3, size=1,aes(x=sale_year, 
                                      y=price, 
                                      group=1,color="red"))+
labs(title="Neighbourhood prices")+
scale_color_discrete(name="Neighborhood",
                       labels=c("neighbourhood1","neighbourhood2","neighbourhood3"))
```

[image]

I tried solving the problem by adding these lines to the code chunk above:

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(2003, 2020, by = 2))+
scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 1000, by = 50))
```

But it introduced another problem:   *Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale*

Comment: Based on how you have geom_line defined, you need to move “color= x” outside the aes definition.

Comment: the `color` aesthetic in `aes()` does not refer to the actual colour. It is rather a name grouping that your are providing. If you want to map colours directly, do it outside of the `aes()` call. OR Provide a named vector to to `scale_color_discrete`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `scale_color_identity` :

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=neighbourhood1,size=1,
       aes(x=sale_year,y=price, group=1,color="blue"))+ geom_line()+
  geom_line(data=neighbourhood2, size=1,aes(x=sale_year, y=price,group=1,color="green"))+
  geom_line(data=neighbourhood3, size=1,aes(x=sale_year, y=price, group=1,color="red"))+
  labs(title="Neighbourhood prices")+
  scale_color_identity(name="Neighborhood",
                       labels=c("neighbourhood1","neighbourhood2","neighbourhood3"), 
                       guide="legend")
```